navigate to other screen on chrome extension
function App() {
  const [isWalletConnected, setIsWalletConnected] = useState(false);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleConnectWalletClick = () => {
    setIsWalletConnected(false);
    navigate('/CreateNewWallet');
    console.log("Connect wallet clicked");
  };
  const handleRestoreWalletClick = () => {
    setIsWalletConnected(false);
    navigate('/RestoreWallet');
    console.log("Restore wallet clicked");
  };


  return (
    
      <div className='button-container'>
        <button className="btn1" onClick={handleConnectWalletClick} disabled={isWalletConnected}>
          Connect a new wallet
        </button>
        <button className="btn2" onClick={handleRestoreWalletClick} disabled={isWalletConnected}>
          Restore an existing wallet
        </button>
      </div>
}

I'm trying to navigate to CreateNewWallet.tsx screen, however, it's somehow not working. btw this is an app on chrome extension, I'm not sure if I missed sth in  manifest.json.
      "default_popup": "index.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
      "storage",
      "activeTab",
      "scripting",
      "webNavigation"
    ],

I want to go to another screen once I click on the Create a New Wallet.

Pages in an extension are just files, so you need to specify .html in the name.

You mean navigate(/CreateNewWallet.tsx) like this? Or ur talking about manifest.json.

It depends on how you define CreateNewWallet. If it's a separate html file in your output folder (dist or build) then you need to use its actual file name.

the CreateNewWallet.tsx file:
`
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import bip39 from 'bip39';
const CreateNewWallet: React.FC = () => {
const [seedPhrase, setSeedPhrase] = useState('');
const generateSeedPhrase = () => {
const mnemonic = bip39.generateMnemonic(256);
setSeedPhrase(mnemonic);
};
return (

New Wallet
Genertate Seed Phrase
{seedPhrase && Your Seed Phrase:${seedPhrase}}

);
};
export default CreateNewWallet;
`

No, it depends on whether it's a separate file in the output build. Also how you register navigation endpoints.
